# Solve some inverse gamma function integral

Tags: gamma-function

I solved 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-b/x} }{x^{a+1}}.x.\frac{b^{a-1}}{\Gamma(a-1)}dx$$
and got result -1 while https://www.integral-calculator.com/ showed result 1. Can someone confirm which one the correct result?

Comment: So many confusing things. What is  $.$ there? Is it multiplication? Why to you keep $\frac{b^{a-1}}{\Gamma(a-1)}$ inside the integral? (It's a constant and it doesn't depend on $x$.) // Anyway if $.$ is multiplication, one can rewrite the integral as: $$\frac{b^{a-1}}{\Gamma(a-1)}\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-b/x}}{x^{a}}dx$$ Now let $x=\frac{1}{t}$ then use the gamma function integral representation. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Yes, that's just multiplication and I have got the final result (=-1). The question is; "Does my result correct?"
It's integral from 0 to infinite, not 0 to 1!

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I typed $1$ instead of $\infty$ in a hurry.